# sql database query to find overlapping time requests

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I'm making a laptop lending system and have a query that checks if the laptops are available for certain dates, however a new feature they want to add in, is to cancel a laptop request at any point. The main thing I'm struggling with is if a laptop request has been cancelled to get my query to recognise that the laptop is now free and can be added to the array. It works on a lend_status system so when the request has been cancelled/completed it changes to a 6. Basically what I need my query to do is to also recognise if a request overlaps with the timings of an already approved request but if the status is 6 then it counts as complete and can be added into the array. 
Hopefully that all makes sense - I'm very new to php and sql and have had a bit of help with this.
I have tried writing a few different queries but it's still not adding the laptop that should technically be available to the array because the request has now been completed.
I've just included the snippet that deals with checking if the laptops are available or not - because it checks if the row count is 0, I can't seem to write the query corrctly.

```
                // Declare available laptops array
                $available_laptops = array();

                // GET ALL LAPTOPS IN OPERATION
                $STH2 = $DBH->prepare("
                    SELECT laptop_id,
                    laptop_name
                    FROM laptops
                    WHERE 1
                ");
                // EXECUTE THE QUERY GETTING THE LAPTOP NAME AND ID FROM FIRST TABLE
                $STH2->execute(array());
                // WHILE LOOP BASED ON FIRST TABLE TO CONNECT THE LATOP NAME AND ID TO THE OTHER TABLE
                while ($row2 = $STH2->fetch()) {
                    // CHECK EACH LAPTOP FOR THE REQUESTED DATES IN THE MAIN TABLE
                    $STH3 = $DBH->prepare("
                        SELECT lend_id
                        FROM laptop_system
                        WHERE (
                        (
                        approved_start_date <= ?
                        AND approved_end_date >= ?
                        ) OR (
                        approved_start_date <= ?
                        AND approved_end_date >= ?
                        ) OR (
                        approved_start_date >= ?
                        AND approved_end_date <= ?
                        )
                        )
                        AND laptop_id = ?

                    ");
                    $STH3->execute(array(
                        $requested_start_date,
                        $requested_start_date,
                        $requested_end_date,
                        $requested_end_date,
                        $requested_start_date,
                        $requested_end_date,
                        // GETTING THE ROW FROM THE FIRST TABLE
                        $row2->laptop_id
                    ));

                    // IF IT'S NOT BOOKED OUT, ADD TO ARRAY -- IF ROWCOUNT IS LESS THAN 1
                    if ($STH3->rowCount() < 1) {
                        $available_laptops[$row2->laptop_id] = $row2->laptop_name;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: php myadmin and trying to use PDO

Comment: You didn't tell us in which table and coloumn the status is stored. Assuming table `laptop_system` I think you have to change the query like this: `AND laptop_id = ?
 AND status != 6`